# ion-searchbar event doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, search

When I search in ion-searchbar, it lists what I'm looking for in seconds, but the main list is reloaded right after.

**home.page.html**

```
<ion-searchbar mode="ios" (ionInput)="getItems($event)" animated></ion-searchbar>
```

**home.page.ts**

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit{
unit = [];
  constructor( private unitService: UnitService) { this.loadUnit();}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.loadUnit();
  }
  loadUnit(){
    this.unitService.getUnit().subscribe(res=>{
      this.unit= res;
    })
  }

   getItems(ev) {
    this.loadUnit();
    let val = ev.target.value;

    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.unit = this.unit.filter((un,name) => {
        return (un.name.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLocaleLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
    }
}
```

**unit.service.ts**

```
  getUnit(){

      return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/units`).pipe(
      map((unit: any[]) => {
        return unit.map((un, index) => {
          un.unIndex = index + 1;
          return un;
        });
      })
    )
  }
```

Comment: It seems that you are not canceling the previous pending requests... If thats the case then have look at switchmap, otherwise upload your code to stackblitz or simillar

Comment: When I use Ionic3, "this.loadUnit ();" he was canceling

Comment: @uncumara strange.. anyways am not able to help unless you provide an uploaded example, maybe someone else...